# Copy absolute URL including div id on button click

Tags: javascript

I am adding few more details.
On each and every page in my website having h2 tags at every section with some graphics and a copy icon next to the section heading.

So when users wanted to copy the url with this section id they can do this and share it with others, when the other person open the URL in the browser then the should scroll to that section and stay.

In my site, every h2 tag is containing copy to clipboard icon, so when I hit the copy icon button, the URL should copy including div id.

Example, the absolute URL is "mysite dot com" and the div id is "process-invoices" so when I click on the copy button then the url should copy like this "mysite.com/#process-invoices"

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;width:1200px;margin:0 auto;">
      <div class="" style="position:sticky;top:20px;height:calc(100% - 20px)">
        <a href="#streamline-collections" style="display:block;">Streamline collections</a>
        <a href="#process-invoices" style="display:block;">Process invoices</a>
        <a href="#track-performance" style="display:block;">Track performance</a>
        <a href="#predict-inflows" style="display:block;">Predict inflows</a>
      </div>

      <div class="" style="width:600px;">
        <div class="wrapper" id="process-invoices" style="height:600px;background-color:#B51E3A;margin:44px 0;">
          <h1>Streamline collections</h1>
          <button class='copy-button'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="streamline-collections" style="height:600px;background-color:#FDC231;margin:44px 0;">
          <h1>Process invoices</h1>
          <button class='copy-button'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="track-performance" style="height:600px;background-color:#1DA4A8;margin:44px 0;">
          <h1>Track performance</h1>
          <button class='copy-button'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="predict-inflows" style="height:600px;background-color:#FF8A65;margin:44px 0;">
          <h1>Predict inflows</h1>
          <button class='copy-button'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your purposes! Since Stackoverflow Snippets have clipboard API blocked there is legacy using `exec` code as well to handle both use cases. In case there is error code fallbacks to `legacy` method,

```js
document.querySelector('.copy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const divId = this.closest('.wrapper').id;
    let baseUrl = window.location.href.split('#')[0]; // Get the URL without the fragment
    const urlToCopy = `${baseUrl}#${divId}`;

    if (navigator.clipboard) {
        // Attempt to use Clipboard API
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(urlToCopy)
            .then(() => console.log('URL copied to clipboard!'))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Error using Clipboard API: ', err);
                fallbackCopyToClipboard(urlToCopy);
            });
    } else {
        // Fallback for browsers without Clipboard API support
        fallbackCopyToClipboard(urlToCopy);
    }
});

function fallbackCopyToClipboard(text) {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    try {
        const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        const msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Fallback: Unable to copy', err);
    }
    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="process-invoices">
  <h1>Process invoices</h1>
  <button class='copy-button'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) has been deprecated and should not be used. Implement the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) instead.

Comment: any updated code on this as you are saying it is deprecated and should not be used. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: @Sarthak Dwivedi It's working but it's duplicating the URL, if the page is already at "mysite.com/#process-invoices" and if you click on button then it's coming like mysite.com/#process-invoices#process-invoices

Comment: @Sarthak Dwivedi  What you provided is exactly what I need, but there is an error which I replied earlier then this.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier You are right, although it wasn't supported on StackOverflow snippet and any online coding platform, and for demo purposes, I ended up going with exec. Anyway, I have updated the code with a working solution.

Comment: @SathishKumar Updated the code after fixing your issue and also accounting for the deprecated option as well.

Comment: Thank you the help, but for some reason the copy code is working inly for one link.

Comment: I have updated the question by added the sample html snippets, so you can run and see the demo.

Comment: @Sarthak Dwivedi

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi You should use document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach(...) so that *all* of the buttons will copy the url, and not just the first one.